# Which Google Play account does IabHelper use?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing a shop of magazines. I need my magazines once be bought to be available at all user's devices. So, I need to synchronize information somehow. I think, it's logical to synchronize by user play market account.

I looked through google's example implementation of in-app billing [Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html), and I found this implementation easy enough to do my first app with in-app billing.

The quiestion is: which Google Play account does `IabHelper` use? For example, there're several Google accounts on device. How to specify which account should be chosen by `IabHelper`?

How to point to `IabHelper` which account to take if there're many of them at device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer1:**

you can use any of account you have. but remember one thing that use one account which is in your registered device  (set google account when first time device started) because to test application, only test account user can buy the product until it will not published(in Google play market).

**Answer2:**

other users can see your product while your application will be published. You are uploading signed apk file with product id and base 64 key to verify that it is your application and your particular product id by the play store. so while any of other user will purchase that product , his Google account will be registered as the purchased product.

**EDIT:**

One more thing you should remember that test account and developer console account should not be equal.

Let me know you required more information.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: How can I determine, which account I want IabHelper to use?
I want my app to work with current selected play account.
Of course, I added all used accounts as test accounts

Comment: I have given in the answer already that use one account which your phone has, because you can not test billing in emulator. you have to test it on device so it is better to use that account which is first time you entered in the phone while your android phone started.

Comment: check my edited answer above. what is the problem with your current selected account? you can simply add your selected account into developer console and simply you can test on it.

Comment: @Maulik the question is how to point to IabHelper which account to take if there're many of them at device?

Comment: @IlyaBlokh thank you for explaining more, according to what I understood from the question, IabHelper or google play store choose that account which your device is registered at google play account. Google play always check the device account which is already registered into google play store first time your phone start or may be after reset your device and set your google account again.

Comment: @IlyaBlokh if you want to use another account in your device, then you can simply reset factory your phone and choose your another account else I have to searched out what is another way without reset our phone.